# Intellij - Persistence entity accessor incorrectly mapped

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have an Oracle database schema that i'm trying to generate persistent mappings from. I'm using the integrated tool built inside Intellij. For the most part, it is working correctly, however sometimes it generates setters with the wrong datatype.

A field gets generated `private Integer expiryFrequency;` which is the correct datatype.

Two overloaded setters get generated, one method is generated with incompatible datatype . See below:

```
    //Valid datatype
    public void setExpiryFrequency(Integer expiryFrequency) {
       this.expiryFrequency = expiryFrequency == null ? 0 : expiryFrequency;
    }  
    //Invalid datatype
    public void setExpiryFrequency(Short expiryFrequency) {
       this.expiryFrequency = expiryFrequency==null ? (short)0:expiryFrequency;
    }
```

I'm sure there is some sort of configuration that is enabling this default behavior. Does anyone know how to disable it?

Comment: When you generate Entity from table, in the Intellij persistence tool window for every table column you can specify the field type, check it before generate.

Comment: @VasileBors The fieldtype is mapping correctly. The problem is that is not mapping one of the accessor's correctly.

Comment: What type has the column in database ?

Comment: @VasileBors it is a integer (number - 5)

Comment: @VasileBors I regenerated the entity and didn't generate the overloaded methods. Seems like it works now.